# How to insert datetime with milliseconds into Access database?

Tags: c#, datetime, ms-access

I am trying to insert a date + time into an Access database using C#. The time string has milliseconds in it, e.g.:

```
"2015-03-23 11:22:33.123"`
```

Here is the code I have:

```
string strName = "somestring";
string strDate = "2015-03-23 11:22:33.123"

sql = @"insert into table_name  ([name], [date]) values (@Name, @Date)";

using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql))
{
    command.Connection = openCon;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", strName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", strDate ); // <-- error here          
    openCon.Open();
    recordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    openCon.Close();
}
```

I get an error at `ExcuteNonQuery()`; if I remove the date time string, then the code works.

So how do I insert datetime with milliseconds into an Access database?

Comment: whats datatype at table for that column?

Comment: It is the default Date/Time type.

Comment: What is the error message _exactly_?

Comment: It will not work with AddWithValue, but it will with Add. Se my corrected answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing up DateTime and String. Always use DateTime for date/time values or convert to DateTime as early as possible.
Thus:

```
string strDate = "2015-03-23 11:22:33.123";
DateTime datDate = DateTime.Parse(strDate);
// ...
//    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", datDate ); // <-- error here 

command.Parameters.Add("@Date",OleDbType.Date);
command.Parameters[0].Value = datDate;                    // <-- no error
```

Note that although Access will store the value correctly, it or VBA will not display the milliseconds but do a 4/5 rounding to the second. This is, of course, of no importance if you only read these values from your C# application.

The value will be inserted correctly as can be seen here when inserted in my Millisecond application:

```
DateTimeMs          SortValue       DateFull                CDouble             RoundSecSQL         MsecSQL MsecVBA SecondDec SecondStd
23-03-2015 11:22:33 60438568953123  23-03-2015 11:22:33.123 42086,4739944792    42086,4739930556    123     123     33,123    33
23-03-2015 11:45:31 60438570330707  23-03-2015 11:45:30.707 42086,4899387384    42086,4899305556    707     707     30,707    31
```

Comment: re: "no error here" - Actually yes, that will produce an error for an OleDbCommand when `.ExecuteNonQuery()` is called. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29207251/2144390) for details.

Comment: True Gord. That was air code and I normally use DataTableAdapters, so I shouldn't play clever using AddWithValue. However, using Add works. See my corrected answer.

Answer (score 5):

The Access "Date/Time" field type has a nominal resolution of one second. That is, when Date/Time values are displayed in Access, [formatted](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add--and-customize-date-and-time-formats-763b9b04-ccf8-46a8-9ee3-6d8f6fb9e2f8#__toc272229486) using pre-defined or custom formats, or manipulated with functions like [DateAdd](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateAdd-Function-63befdf6-1ffa-4357-9424-61e8c57afc19) or [DatePart](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/DatePart-Function-26868a79-5505-4e5a-8905-6001372223fa), the smallest unit of time we can specify is a *second*.

**Using OLEDB with .NET**

When using `.AddWithValue` against an Access database via `System.Data.OleDb`, a `DateTime` parameter for a Date/Time field must not have a Millisecond value or the insert/update will fail. That is,

```cs
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("2015-03-23 11:22:33.123");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dt);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

will fail with

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

However, as Gustav points out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29205112/2144390) we can use `.Add` with `OleDbType.Date` to add a `DateTime` parameter that does include milliseconds,

```cs
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("2015-03-23 11:22:33.123");
cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Date).Value = dt;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and the value will be stored, intact, in the Access Date/Time field. We can verify this by retrieving the stored value and checking it

```cs
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [date] FROM table_name WHERE ID = 13";
DateTime rtn = Convert.ToDateTime(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
Console.WriteLine(rtn.Millisecond);
```

... which prints "123", showing that the millisecond component is part of the returned value.

The trick is that Access itself does not give us the tools to effectively *work with* the millisecond portions of those Date/Time values. To do so from within Access/VBA requires some extra coding as explained in an article on another site [here](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/39046).

(Of course, if you're only interested in pulling the values back into a .NET application then you can just use the code snippet above.)

**Using ODBC with .NET**

Using the same approach with `System.Data.Odbc` yields slightly different results. The Access ODBC driver will accept a `DateTime` parameter with a Millisecond value for both `.Add` and `.AddWithValue` but it will *NOT* store the milliseconds.

Also, if we try to retrieve a Date/Time value with milliseconds that was stored using OLEDB, the Access ODBC driver *removes* the milliseconds. That is, if we try to use the following ODBC code to retrieve the "millisecond value" we stored via the OLEDB example above ...

```cs
// cmd is now an OdbcCommand object
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [date] FROM table_name WHERE ID = 13";
DateTime rtn = Convert.ToDateTime(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
Console.WriteLine(rtn.Millisecond);
```

... it prints "0", even though we can verify that the millisecond portion of the Double value has been stored in the database by doing

```cs
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CDbl([date]) AS foo FROM table_name WHERE ID = 13";
Double rtn = Convert.ToDouble(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
Console.WriteLine(rtn);
```

and inspecting the decimal portion of the Double value.

**Alternatives**

If you want to stay within the nominal 1-second resolution of the Date/Time field type you can ...

Round the value to the nearest second:

```cs
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("2015-03-23 11:22:33.123");
if (dt.Millisecond >= 500)
{
    dt = dt.AddSeconds(1);
}
dt = dt.AddMilliseconds(-dt.Millisecond);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dt);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Or, if you want to keep the milliseconds then you will either have to store the truncated (not rounded) Date/Time and the milliseconds in separate fields, or perhaps just store the original string value in a Text field.

Comment: The design of Access is really confusing! If it does store milliseconds in Date/Time field why it can not accept DateTime contain milliseconds? Anyway, I will accept this answer as accepted if no better answer appears :-)

Comment: Access can and will store milliseconds - just not natively, and that's where the confusion arises. You have to use custom code in VBA. However, ..Net handles milliseconds, and using Add and not AddWithValue you can store your milliseconds. See my corrected answer.

Comment: Thanks for the summing up, Gord. I was not aware of the ODBC behaviour of ignoring milliseconds completely.

Answer (score 1):

You have to try like this:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", GetDateWithMilliseconds(strDate));

private DateTime GetDateWithoutMilliseconds(DateTime d)
{
    command new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, d.Day, d.Hour, d.Minute, d.Second,d.Milliseconds);
}
```

The reason why you are getting the error is because when you use OleDbType by AddWithValue then it is `DBTimeStamp`, but Access wants a `OleDbType.Date`. Check the [MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320435) for details

Or you can try like this:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@Date", OleDbType.Date).Value = strDate;
```

Comment: Do I need convert `string strDate` to `DateTime d` by using Convert.ToDateTime(strDate)?

Comment: @TRX:- If possible then do it!

Comment: You should never use strings for date/time.

Comment: @Gustav:- That was not the question and btw OP has asked to change it from String to Date for which I have recommended to proceed for! :)

Comment: OK, you are right, but the word "possible" struck me.

Comment: @Gustav:- I am not aware of the contrainst which OP has  thats why I said if its possible ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try using this

```
string strDate = "2015-03-23 11:22:33"
```

Comment: Do you mean Access can not store milliseconds in Date/Time type?

Comment: No Access stored millisecond in Date/Time type but millisecond should not be in decimal format. It should be like this                                            string strDate = "2015-03-23 11:22:33"

Comment: That is not correct. This is not VBA but .Net and date/time should never be strings. No exceptions.

Comment: @TRX have you tried code using  below line                                                         string strDate = "2015-03-23 11:22:33"

Comment: @IJAJMULANI "2015-03-23 11:22:33" does not has milliseconds, isn't it? :/