Counting unique value of a column (e.g. UserID) each day of a certain month
Suppose I have the following LoginInfo table.
LoginInfo



UserID (Short Text)
LoginTime (Date/Time)




...
...


UserA
2024/03/31 ...


UserA
2024/03/31 11:22:23


UserA
2024/03/31 19:23:59


UserB
2024/03/01 09:13:53


UserC
2024/04/01 08:23:02


UserA
2024/04/02 ...


...
...



I want to tally up the number of unique UserID (active users) for each day for the month of March, 2024 (2024/03/01 - 2024/03/31). How would I write an MS Access SQL to do that in an ascending order. In other words the end result will be something like
ActiveUserMar2024



ActiveUsers (Integer)
LogDate (Short Text)




20,500
2024/03/01


18,348
2024/03/02


...
...


125,121
2024/03/31



Also it seems that Date/Time data type for MS Access does not support milliseconds (SSS in YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss.SSS)

Try this: SELECT  COUNT(UserID ) AS ActiveUsers,  FORMAT(YEAR(LoginTime )*10000+MONTH(LoginTime )*100+DAY(LoginTime ),"0000/00/00") AS [Date] FROM LoginInfo WHERE YEAR(LoginTime)=2024 AND MONTH(LoginTime)=3 GROUP BY FORMAT(YEAR(LoginTime )*10000+MONTH(LoginTime )*100+DAY(LoginTime ),"0000/00/00") 

Regarding milliseconds, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29204135/how-to-insert-datetime-with-milliseconds-into-access-database

@ShahramAlemzadeh This almost does what I want except that if the same UserID is logged in (appears) more than once in a day, then those are also counted as well.

@June7 From what I understand of How to insert datetime with milliseconds into Access database?, in order to add milliseconds into Date/Time data type, you have to write a VBA script.

Return DISTINCT date and user then aggregate that data. Use a nested subquery. For the data sample given, there is 1 unique user per day.
SELECT Count(*) AS ActiveUsers, LogDate 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT UserID, DateValue(LoginTime) AS LogDate FROM LoginInfo)
WHERE Format(LogDate,"yyyymm")=202403
GROUP BY LogDate;


This does what I want. Thank you very much. Personal Note: for the requsted resulting heading just change  Cnt -> ActiveUsers.

Oh, I forgot to use and can certainly use any alias name you prefer. Edited answer.
